# TextBox Part ReadOnly

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am creating an WPF UI which has a console as part of it. For this I want to set a part of the `TextBox` as read-only, but still be able to input something at the end of the `TextBox` and also be able to delete that part.

Is it possible to make only a part of the WPF `TextBox` read-only or would I need to work with an event and code this my self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that this is possible with the default WPF `TextBox`. However, there is another way you can achieve a console-like control in  a different way. Create a `ConsoleOutput` property of type `ObservableCollection<string>` which holds the lines of text displayed in your console and a property `ConsoleInput` for the current input line in your view model. Do not forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, otherwise the user interface will not react to changes of `ConsoleInput`. Additionally, create a command `RunCommand`, which will be executed when you confirm or run a command in the console.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ConsoleOutput { get; }

private string _consoleInput;
public string ConsoleInput
{
   get => _consoleInput;
   set
   {
      if (value.Equals(_consoleInput))
         return;

      _consoleInput = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}

public ICommand RunCommand { get; }
```

Initialize the properties in the constructor like below. The implementation of the `RunCommand` simply adds the newly confirmed line of console input to the collection of console outputs and empties the input.

```
public YourViewModel()
{
   //... other code.
   ConsoleOutput = new ObservableCollection<string>();
   OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ConsoleOutput));
   
   RunCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteRun);
   OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RunCommand));
}
   
private void ExecuteRun()
{
   ConsoleOutput.Add(ConsoleInput);
   ConsoleInput = string.Empty;
}
```

Then create the controls and bind the properties. A `ScrollViewer` ensures, that there will be a scrollbar, once the console output exceeds to window. There is an `ItemsControl` that displays all console outputs so far and a `TextBox` below for inputs. It has no border so it does not stand out. The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the `TextBox` is bound to the `RunCommand`, which means the current input is added to the console output and cleared.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <StackPanel>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleOutput}" />
      <TextBox BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding ConsoleInput, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
         <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding RunCommand}"/>
         </TextBox.InputBindings>
      </TextBox>
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is the output. The last element is the `TextBox` that takes the input until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Sample of multiple lines of output and the line currently typed.]

Comment: That looks like a very nice approach I will give this a try too. At the moment I have something where I check if the changes are in the last line and If it still "StartsWith" the last Input. It jsut deletes the input when entered at the wrong part currently xD

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make only a Part of the WPF TextBox ReadOnly

To answer your question: No, it's not possible to make only a part of the `TextBox` read-only using any built-in functionality.

You will have to implement this yourself somehow. Maybe you could consider using several `TextBox` elements where only the last one is editable or something.

Comment: K will have a look. Proboply also just reacting with Listeners

Comment: thx for remembering me